# How can I read 'property' file type in C + + (or Boost), like: language="en"

Tags: c++, boost, settings, ini

I'm trying to parse a file with the contents below using **Boost :: program_options / property_tree.**

#### settings file:

```
app.autorun.message_bar_seen=1
core.flash_version=11
core.clock_delta=-1
autologin.canonical_username="myusername66"
language="en"
network.listen_port=45418
autologin.blob="DbIDiqbdOegNS0hDBUYVWUYAuio"
autologin.username="myusername66"
```

But it is not a valid INI file, because it has no Sections, and their values ​​are in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

you could either create your own parser, or you could change your file by removing quotes and adding a section at the front. like so:

```
[emptysection]
app.autorun.message_bar_seen=1
core.flash_version=11
core.clock_delta=-1
autologin.canonical_username=myusername66
language="en"
network.listen_port=45418
autologin.blob=DbIDiqbdOegNS0hDBUYVWUYAuio
autologin.username=myusername66
```